# Problems with the video rendering time

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, timeline, optimization

I'm new with blender and I have some issues with my rendering time.

I have made an animation that is 2:35 longer. I left the computer rendering the full weekend (it is in my office so I couldn't take a look during the process) and when I arrive to the office the rendering process is around the 1:35. I thought that is enough just to make my test and I stopped it.

But when I saw the video that blender generated, the video is 25 seconds long.

I don't know why can it be, I thought about the problem of the screen saver and the computer shut down, but that shouldn't allowed me to see that the rendering process was until 1:35, isn't it?

I'm working with Blender 2,75a for Mac.

I'm new here so I don't know which kind of information can be useful or not. I'm using blender for short time so I don't know either if I have done something wrong with the setups and all those stuffs.

I will try to upload the file, if you can take a look on it.

Thanks for your attention.

Jezujr.

Comment: A few tips for long renders: disable the power settings on your computer that might put it to sleep or shut down. Screensavers use some (not a lot ) computing power so it's better to have the monitor go blank and have all of the computer resources to render. For long projects render as an image sequence, not as video, that way if the render fails you don't have to start over.

Comment: And, how are you sure your animation is 2:35? that info should come from how many frames your file has and the animation framerate that is set...

Comment: Hello again,

First at all, Thanks for your answers. I could solve the problem and was something that I didn't expected.
I have made the video in .avi and I'm working with Quick Time Player, so when the program try to open the file converting it into .mov, it just do a piece of it.

About how long was the video I knew because I had setup the program with the frames numbers and the frames/second. 
In my timeline I could see the seconds with the option of show seconds, because of that I knew that it wasn't working well.

Thanks again for all.